# Laravel 5.7 Authentication error credentials not matching records

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

so i'm doing this uni project in Laravel 5.7 and i wanted to add authentication, i installed the premade Laravel authentication solution using this command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

But i noticed it uses email instead of a username, in the context of my project the email isn't even one of the attributes of a user so i did a little research on how to use a username for authentication instead of an e-mail and i followed a video tutorial on youtube but i didn't work for me even though i did the exact same steps. This is my users table structure : (id, username, password, telephone, usertype, remember_token, created_at, updated_at)

this is my login.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Pseudo Utilisateur') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('username'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

This is user.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'password', 'telephone', 'usertype'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

this is LoginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function username(){

      return 'username';
    }
}
```

i added a user through phpmyadmin and tried to login yet i get an error  : "These credentials do not match our records."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you hashed your password ? when you insert data using phpmyadmin

Comment: @Md.SukelAli No i didn't, it's not hashed or crypted

Comment: Then it's not going to work. Laravel always hashed your input password and then checked with database password. You should use hashed password in you database.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: use bcrypt() function.

Comment: Thanks, so as i mentioned above i don't have a registration form so i used php artisan tinker command and got the hashed version of my password than updated the one in my database (my database has the hashed password now) and still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the username value on Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers
Change the email to username.

```
public function username()
    {
        return 'email'; //change this to username
    }
```

Comment: I did so and it didn't work, i think that the username method in the LoginController overrides the one in AuthenticatesUsers so same outcome

Comment: put that username function on the logincontroller to override the default email as login

Answer (score 0):

> First write "php artisan migrate:fresh"
>   and write the code above
>   Lastly write "php artisan migrate"

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
 {
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(150); //database has storage of 150 and is extended to 150;
}
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
}
```